# My bar plots are automatically reordered in an order that is not consistent with my data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

I'm using ggplot to make bar graphs of data. I have everything ordered as I want it in my data frame but when I plot it, it is rearranged in some random order. How do I tell it to leave the bars in the order of the data frame? Thank you

iris Example below. In iris data frame species are ordered setosa, 
versicolor, virginica. They are ordered in reverse on the bar plot. It appears to be descending. This is not the case with my plots. Mine are in no obvious order.

```
ggplot(iris[iris$Sepal.Width ==3.0,]) + aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length) + geom_col() + coord_flip()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and edit your question so the community can best help you. To start, consider using `dput()` to share some of your data.

Comment: How did you arrange your dataframe ?  did you convert it in a factor format ? Using the `iris` dataset, I"m not able to reproduce your error. Please provide more information about your dataset and your code.

Comment: Not sure what factor form means. Sorry, I'm still new to R. My data frame is ordered with species in the first column followed by the combined column (site data) and then abundance column (the numerical data). The data frame is in long format with species repeated in each of the sites. So the data are ordered by site.

Comment: Please share an example of your data. It will make easier to assist you. Seee @OTStats's comment for how to provide a reproducible example

Comment: There are only two possible orderings: (1) alphabetical (the default) and (2) by order of factor levels. You can look at `sapply(iris, class)` and see the column classes. Maybe look around a bit, I found this about factors: https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/12-supp-factors/index.html

Comment: [the canonical ggplot ordering question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph) is bars, but this works the same way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reorder the columns, try this

```
ggplot(iris[iris$Sepal.Width ==3.0,]) + aes(x= factor(Species, levels = c("versicolor", "setosa", "virginica")), y=Sepal.Length) + geom_col() + coord_flip() + xlab("Species")
```